# how many times a token can be repeated in regex

Tags: java, regex

I am a beginner in regex. I read that `\b[1-9][0-9]{2,4}\b` matches a number between `100` and `99999`, but what is the difference between `\b[1-9][0-9]{2,4}\b` and `\b[1-9]{2,4}\b` and why mentioned pattern matches a number between `100` and `99999`?

I think because `min=2` and `max=4` pattern matches a number between 10 and 9999, because the minimum two-digit number is 10 and the maximum four-digit number is 9999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is not entirely correct.

```
  xy{2,4} matches x followed by 2 to 4 y => xyy or xyyy or xyyyy
```

In your case `[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` matches any digit between `[1-9]` followed by any `2 to 4` digits in `[0-9]`. So it matches any number between

```
100 - 1 coming from [1-9] and 00 coming from [0-9]{2,4}
```

and

```
99999 - 9 coming from [1-9] and 9999 coming from [0-9]{2,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but what is different between `\b[1-9][0-9]{2,4}\b` and `\b[1-9]{2,4}\b` ...?

In the second regex you cant have any `0`s

so 10 is no match in the second one.

AND

`[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` matches 1 00 to 9 9999 (the first part is 1-9 and than you can add 00 - 9999)

`{2,4}` belongs only to `[0-9]` ... so it is exactly one `[1-9]` and 2-4 `[0-9]`

to try out the regex, you can use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

The expression says: First a blank, then a digit in range 1-9, then two to four digits in range 0-9. Thus, the minimum number is 100.

Answer (score 0):

`\b[1-9][0-9]{2,4}\b` ==>

`\b` ==> ensures word boundary. ie., doesn't allow your string to be inside another number string like `111111000011111`

`[1-9][0-9]{2,4}` ==> a digit 1 to 9 followed by  digits (between 0 to 9) whose min length =2 and max length = 4. This matches strings like : 132,10234 but NOT 012 or 11.

`\b[1-9]{2,4}\b` ==> matches 1 to 9 2 to 4 times. i.e, 19, 193, 1934 are all valid